# Node.js + Angular.js promises sync issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular-promise

I am working on a chat app which is Node.js + MongoDB (Mongoose library) on the server side, and Angular.js on the client side.

I have a database collection (MongoDB) for rooms (all the rooms in the app), which looks like this:

```
// ------- creating active_rooms model -------
var active_rooms_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    room_name: String,
    users: [String]
});
var active_rooms = mongoose.model('active_rooms', active_rooms_schema);
```

This database contains a room with all its users (i.e. "my cool room" with users: "mike", "joe", and "dave").

What I want to do is - every time a user wants to be in a chat room (with some room name) in my Angular.js client, I want to:

1. Create the room if it is not exists
2. Push that user into the users array of the  room.

I know that because of 1, I will always have a room with an array of users.

This is my Angular relevant code: (I cannot give here the whole app because it is way too large and not relevant.)

```
$scope.enterRoom = function(info) {
    $q.when(create_room_if_not_exists($scope.room)).then(add_user_to_room($scope.name, $scope.room));
    $location.path("chat");
}


var create_room_if_not_exists = function(room_name) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    is_room_already_exists({
        'name': room_name
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (!response.data.is_room_exists) {
            register_room({
                'name': room_name
            });
            console.log("room: " + room_name + ", was created");
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

var add_user_to_room = function(user_name, room_name) {
    console.log(user_name)
    add_user_to_room_request({
        'user_name': user_name,
        'room_name': room_name
    });
}

var is_room_already_exists = function(info) {
    return $http({
        url: '/is_room_already_exists',
        method: 'POST',
        data: info
    });
}

var add_user_to_room_request = function(info) {
    $http({
        url: '/add_user_to_room',
        method: 'POST',
        data: info
    });
}

var register_room = function(info) {
    return $http({
        url: '/register_room',
        method: 'POST',
        data: info
    });
}
```

What happens is that the 2nd action happens before the 1st one. When I print a log into the console, I see that, and I don't know why.

Both of these actions arrive through an HTTP request to the server - so I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: As shown the two XHRs will chain. The location path will change before the two XHRs complete. When you say "2nd action happens before the 1st one" are you talking about the XHRs not chaining or the location changing before the XHRs complete?

Comment: I am talking about the XHRs not chaining

Comment: Side note: you might want to try simply adding the user to the room first and then only attempt to create the room if that first call failed. It will completely eliminate the need for the `is_room_already_exists` function.

Comment: Secondly you might want to adjust your server-side route for /register_room to also take a user_name. Then you can automatically add the user who is registering the room to that room server-side, thus eliminating an additional request from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am talking about the XHRs not chaining

A common cause of problems with chaining is failure to return promises to the chain:

```
var add_user_to_room = function(user_name, room_name) {
    console.log(user_name)
    //add_user_to_room_request({
    return add_user_to_room_request({
  //^^^^^^ ----- be sure to return returned promise
        'user_name': user_name,
        'room_name': room_name
    });
}
```

If chaining is done properly, `$q.defer` is not necessary:

```
var create_room_if_not_exists = function(room_name) {
    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    //is_room_already_exists({
    return is_room_already_exists({
  //^^^^^^ --- be sure to return derived promise
        'name': room_name
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (!response.data.is_room_exists) {
            console.log("room: " + room_name + ", to be created");
            //register_room({
            return register_room({
          //^^^^^^ ----- return promise to further chain
                'name': room_name
            });
            //deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            return room_name;
          //^^^^^^ ----- return to chain data
        };
    }, function(error) {
        //deferred.reject(error.data);
        throw error;
      //^^^^^ ------- throw to chain rejection
    });
    //return deferred.promise;
}
```

If a promise is returned properly, `$q.when` is not necessary:

```
$scope.enterRoom = function(info) {
    //$q.when(create_room_if_not_exists($scope.room))
    //   .then(add_user_to_room($scope.name, $scope.room));
    return create_room_if_not_exists($scope.room)
        .then(function() {
            return add_user_to_room($scope.name, $scope.room));
        }).then(function()
            $location.path("chat")
        });
}
```

The rule of thumb with functional programming is -- **always return something**.

*Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and **since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further)**, it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.*

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.enterRoom = function (info) {
  return create_room_if_not_exists($scope.room)).then(function(){
    return add_user_to_room_request({ 'user_name': $scope.name, 'room_name': $scope.name });
  }).then(function(){
    $location.path('chat');
  });
}


var create_room_if_not_exists = function (room_name) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return is_room_already_exists({ 'name': room_name }).then(function (response) {
        if (!response.data.is_room_exists) {
            console.log("room: " + room_name + ", is being created");
            return register_room({ 'name': room_name });
        }
        return response;
    })
}

   var is_room_already_exists = function (info) {
        return $http({
            url: '/is_room_already_exists',
            method: 'POST',
            data: info
        });
    }

 var add_user_to_room_request = function (info) {
            return $http({
                url: '/add_user_to_room',
                method: 'POST',
                data: info
            });
        }

   var register_room = function (info) {
            return $http({
                url: '/register_room',
                method: 'POST',
                data: info
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but still no luck. I added logging to the client and I see this order:
is_room_already_exists, 
add_user_to_room_request, 
register_room. where it should be: 
is_room_already_exists
register_room
add_user_to_room_request

Comment: @Matoy that is simply not possible with the code I've provided.

Comment: you are right. sorry. your solution is correct. my code was not refreshed correctly on the server. thanks!